# How to use Google Cloud Platform TPU v3?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-tpu

I found a tutorial on [How to Set up an Instance to Run a Jupyter Notebook in GCP?](https://tudip.com/blog-post/run-jupyter-notebook-on-google-cloud-platform/)

This tutorial is about how to run Jupyter Notebook in Google Cloud Platform. I would like to use also TPU v3. I also read the documentation https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/quickstart. But unfortunately it doesn't help me.

My questions now are:

- How do I create a TPU v3 and use it in the Jupyter Notebook?
- How do I read and write data when TPU v3 is selected as run time?

In Google Colab I do the following in order to use the TPU:

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf
print("Tensorflow version " + tf.__version__)

try:
  tpu = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver()  # TPU detection
  print('Running on TPU ', tpu.cluster_spec().as_dict()['worker'])
except ValueError:
  raise BaseException('ERROR: Not connected to a TPU runtime; please see the previous cell in this notebook for instructions!')

tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(tpu)
tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(tpu)
tpu_strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(tpu)
.
.
.
batch_size = 16 * tpu_strategy.num_replicas_in_sync
.
.
.
with tpu_strategy.scope(): 
  model = create_model()
model.summary()
```

How do I use a TPU v3 with Google Cloud Platform?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you were able to setup a Google Cloud Platform VM and use that VM to host a Jupyter notebook.

One thing to note is that you can create a Jupyter notebook directly in Google Cloud with this guide: https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/create-new

If you really wanted to make your own VM and host Jupyter on there, you could try following this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/tutorials/mnist-2.x

Note there is the step `ctpu up ...` that will create a VM and a TPU. You could use that VM and follow the steps in the first tutorial you linked to turn that VM into your Jupyter host. Then follow the rest of the steps in [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/tutorials/mnist-2.x) from within a notebook hosted on that VM and see if it works

Overall I'd recommend:

- Use [this](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/create-new) if you want to use Google Cloud + Jupyter
- Use Colab if you're OK with any notebook and want to use TPUs
- Use [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/quickstart) if you want the best experience using TPUs and are OK with not having a notebook